# Complexity of multiplying Cauchy matrix by a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, cauchy-matrices

I want to find the matrix-vector product:

$b=C \times a$

where $b=[b_1, ..., b_n]$ is the unknown vector, $a=[a_1, ..., a_n]$ is the known vector, and C is the coefficients matrix.

The complexity to calculate b is $O(n^2)$

Assuming that the C matrix is a Cauchy matrix $n \times n$  matrix as follows:

\begin{align}
C[i,j] = \frac{1}{x_i+y_i}
\end{align}

Is it possible to calculate b with less complexity?

Comment: this is the problem of multiplying a vector by a matrix, not solving linear equations...

Comment: @DimaPasechnik If you replace "solving set of linear equations" by "computing the matrix-vector product", the question is completely OK. It is about whether you can compute a product of this matrix (depending on $2n$ parameters) with smaller complexity than $O(n^2)$ for general MV product.

Comment: I've edited the question. Hopefully someone reviews the changes.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a brief summary (see [Wikipedia and linked arXiv article for more](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_matrix#Generalization))

1. $b=Ca$ can be approximated in $O(n\log n)$ time using the [Fast multipole method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_multipole_method)
2. LU factorization of $C$ using the GKO algorithm, this takes $O(n^2)$ time. See [this paper for how to implement this well](http://arxiv.org/abs/0903.4569)  (i.e., $a=C^{-1}b$)
3. If you are not worried about approximations or numerical instability, then you can handle this in $O(n\log^2 n)$ time (i.e., compute $a \approx C^{-1}b$)